# how can i say "if display of #menu is block then set the display of #button is block" in js and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want the navicon to turn into a X when the menu is open. Does anyone know haw to do that? I haven't really tried anything because I have little knowledge of js and JavaScript.

Thank you

Comment: It is possible to do with pure CSS

Comment: Please explain how

Answer (score 0):

is this what you need?

```
span{
  display:block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 4px;
  background: black;
  margin:3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform-origin: 20% 60%;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}
span.active1{
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

see this working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/yg1v0wtm/2/

Comment: yes it is what i need but it doesnt work for me even when i make a new file